# Best practice: store image and text in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, data-structures

I am doing a simple app where I take a picture, fill some text from the UI and store the image + text together.

Eventually the user can select the picture from a recyclerview and edit the associated text (or delete the whole image + text group).

I have no hint on what kind of data structure should be used. 
I heard that SQL lite should be used for such tasks - since the text data could change according to the user actions, but I think that using tables (one or more) for the purpose of storing images and text could be overkill - also because I don't expect to have a lot of images in my app.

I'm wondering if any other data structure is available for this purpose (similar to C strctures, or python dictionaries).
Also, any kind of hint about keyword to search for this topic or resource would be really appreciated.

Just for the sake of discussion, I am developing using kotlin.

Comment: Please note that downvoting a question without providing a rationale is not going to be very useful. At least, not for the one who asks the question. 
If I had some code to share, I would have shared.

Comment: Opinion-based software architecture questions like this are a better fit for the [Software Engineering Stack Exchange](//softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) (and you'll likely get better answers there). Please review [what types of questions are on-topic there](//softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (and [what aren't](//softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)) before posting there to make sure that your question is on-topic. See [Can I ask design-related questions on Stack Overflow?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252139) for why these questions are off-topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For storing images, you should store them as files, and store file paths of those images in the database with text. Moreover, when you read it back you can use **Picasso** or **Glide** to load those image paths into `ImageView`.
Also, if you want to store images in external storage, make you request runtime-permission and add permission to the manifest file.

However, if you store files in internal storage, you don't need to request permission.

Learn more about [Runtime-Permission](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting) and [Storage](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage) in Android.

I would suggest use [Room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room) for working with SQLite in Android.

Comment: thanks @Seanghay, I think room was the keyword I was looking for.